# Extension methods vs overloading

Tags: c#, extension-methods, overloading

I'm wondering whether method overloading that will be mainly be there as **convenience** for the caller should be implemented on the interface or as extension methods? I've looked but I could not find any official guidelines when it comes to methods that are overloaded merely for convenience' sake.

I know that if you own the code you should probably not use extension methods but is there a difference when it comes to methods that are just there for convenience. I feel like they would clutter the interface but maybe that's just me.

**Regarding duplicate:** My question is more about method overloading when the overloads are there for convenience for the caller and will not differ between implementations

Example implementation with method overloading in the interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    //This feels cluttered since they don't add any new functionality, 
    // they are just here to be convenient for the caller.
    void Bar(int a);
    void Bar(int a, int b);
    void Bar(int a, int b, int c);
}
```

Example implementation with extension methods:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar(int a);
}

public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static void Bar(this IFoo foo, int a, int b)
    {
        //...
    }

    public static void Bar(this IFoo foo, int a, int b, int c)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: This feels opinion based... imho the main difference is: if you provide the methods in the interface, then every class _implementing_ the interface _must_ implement them, but is also _free_ to provide a "different than usual" implementation. If you provide it as an extension, then noone else _needs_ to implement them, but also noone can provide their own _overrides_. It's "take it, or leave it/create your own extension (with a different name)".

Comment: Overloading in your case is definitely better option. Implementation of the interface should be placed in the class that implements it, not in extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should use *extension methods* if we are quite sure that the methods are the *same* for the *all* (including potential) interface implementation:

```
  public interface IFoo {
    void Bar(int a); 
  } 

  public static class FooExtensions {
    public static void Bar(this IFoo foo, int a, int b) {...}
    public static void Bar(this IFoo foo, int a, int b, int c) {...}
  }
```

We can implement *different* `Bar(int a)` methods

```
  public MyFoo : IFoo {
    void Bar(int a) { /* MyFoo algorithm here */}
  }

  public MyOtherFoo : IFoo {
    void Bar(int a) { /* some other - MyOtherFoo - algorithm here */}
  }
```

But `Bar(int a, b)` as well as `Bar(int a, b, c)` are still be the same:

```
  new MyFoo().Bar(1, 2);      // FooExtensions.Bar(IFoo, int, int) called
  new MyOtherFoo().Bar(1, 2); // FooExtensions.Bar(IFoo, int, int) called
```

If, say, `Bar(int a, int b)` can *vary* from implementation to implementation we have have to add it into interface:

```
  public interface IFoo {
    void Bar(int a); 
    void Bar(int a, int b); 
  } 

  ...

  public MyFoo : IFoo {
    void Bar(int a)        { /* MyFoo algorithm here */}
    void Bar(int a, int b) { /* MyFoo algorithm here */} 
  }

  public MyOtherFoo : IFoo {
    void Bar(int a)        { /* some other - MyOtherFoo - algorithm here */}
    void Bar(int a, int b) { /* some other - MyOtherFoo - algorithm here */} 
  }
```

If *almost* all interface implementations have the same algorithm it'll be boring to put the boiler plate code. However, in **C# 8.0** we are going to have a good compromise - *default method implmentation*, e.g.

```
  public interface IFoo {
    void Bar(int a); 
    void Bar(int a, int b) {
      /* Default code here */
    } 
  } 

  // uses default code for Bar(int a, int b)
  public MyFoo : IFoo {
    void Bar(int a)        { /* MyFoo algorithm here */}
  }

  // uses its own code for Bar(int a, int b)
  public MyOtherFoo : IFoo {
    void Bar(int a)        { /* some other - MyOtherFoo - algorithm here */}
    void Bar(int a, int b) { /* some other - MyOtherFoo - algorithm here */} 
  }
```

Comment: This was the answer that I was looking for, thank you! The overloads will never differ from the implementations, they are merely there for convenience so that different callers won't have to transform their data.